# Django, if object does not exist, getting error on AND queryset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to run an if condition based on the value returned by running a query in Django.

the query I want to run is:

```
q = Voterlist.objects.get(Q(voter=request.user),Q(verse=verse)):
```

now, if q exists, I want to update the vote column of Voterlist.
Else I want to add that object in database. The problem here is, if the object already exists i.e q exists, then it runs fine, but if 
q does not exist then I get a 500 error code and that query does not run. I tried using a try block and I also tried to do an if statement using the query but I am unable to run this if q does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the try except like this?

```
try:
    q = Voterlist.objects.get(Q(voter=request.user),Q(verse=verse))
except (VoterList.DoesNotExist, VoterList.MultipleObjectsReturned):
    # do something
    pass
```

**update**: you have to check for MultipleObjectsReturned exception as well because multiple objects might be returned by that query; depends on how you want to do it, in one or multiple try catch blocks;

Also, you might be better off writing the get queryset without Q objects like this, which is basically the same thing:

```
Voterlist.objects.get(voter=request.user, verse=verse)
```

Comment: i have not tried VoterList.DoesNotExist, will try that now

Answer (score 1):

you dont need `Q` Object for this query, just do:

```
q = Voterlist.objects.get(voter=request.user, verse=verse)
```

and as BodgiG suggested, you can catch the case where `q` returns DoesNotExist.

```
try:
   q = Voterlist.objects.get(Q(voter=request.user),Q(verse=verse))
except VoterList.DoesNotExist:
   # do something
   pass
```